# how to eval a cond case and return function object?

Tags: hy

got TypeError: Don't know how to wrap <class 'function'>: <function test_cond_list_fn.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001B879FD3D08>

when run

```
;a fn object
(setv a_fn (fn [x] (+ 1 x)))
;a mock predicator
(setv predicator True)
;inject predicator and a_fn into a (cond ..)
(setv cond_expr `(cond [(~predicator) [~a_fn]]))
;eval at another place 
(eval cond_expr)
```

How to create the "cond_expr" so that get the result [a_fn] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `eval` a `HyExpression` it must first be compiled to Python ast. While you're allowed to put arbitrary objects into a `HyExpression`, that does not mean you can compile it. (There has been a little talk of [simulating this feature](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/919), but it's not available currently.)

The Hy compiler can only do this for a certain set of data types called Hy Model types, or for a few other types that can be automatically converted to these Hy Models.

There's no obvious way to represent a function *object* in Python ast, so there is no Hy Model for it. But you can compile a function *definition*.

```
=> (setv a-fn '(fn [x] (+ 1 x)))
=> (setv cond-expr `(cond [True ~a-fn]))
=> (eval cond-expr)
<function <lambda> at 0x0000020635231598>
```

Or a function's *symbol*.

```
=> (defn b-fn [x] (- x 1))
=> (setv cond-expr2 `(cond [True b-fn]))
=> (eval cond-expr)
<function <lambda> at 0x0000020635208378>
```